# UIScrollView not starting at minimum zoom

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I am trying to get the UIScrollView to work in my Monotouch application.  No matter what I set the SetZoomScale() to it always ignores my starting ratio.  Ideally I want it to 0.5f zoom when I start up.

```
theGraphScrollView = new UIScrollView(theRect);  // Half of the screen height, full width of screen
this.View.AddSubview(theGraphScrollView);

UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView(thePhotoSource.LoadPhotoFromFile("IMG_0_17.JPG"));
theGraphScrollView.ContentSize = imageView.Image.Size;  // This is much bigger than the screen width and height.
theGraphScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3f;
theGraphScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 0.5f;
theGraphScrollView.SetZoomScale(0.5f, true);
theGraphScrollView.AddSubview(imageView);
theGraphScrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { return imageView;   };
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `SetZoomScale()` at the end.

`ViewForZoomingInScrollView` should be hooked up prior to changing the zoom.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `SetZoomScale`, [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) tries to animate the view, but you've neither added the image yet, nor set your delegate to inform `theGraphScrollView` which view to zoom.

Move `SetZoomScale` to the very end and you'll be set. If this is in your `ViewDidLoad`, you might also want to set the 2nd parameter of `SetZoomScale` to `false` to prevent the graph from animating when you first load the view. That's of course, a matter of preference.